# SPDIF, sound goes away for a second and then comes back

Tags: audio

I have this new setup with SPDIF connected 2.0 speakers.

The problem is the sound goes mute for a second and then comes back. This happens randomly, not very often - with like ~10 min intervals.

I'm using non-standard cable, cause the one that came with the speakers is too short. Standard cable used to work fine when I did the initial testing. Audio source is Gigabyte GA-Z170X-Ultra Gaming motherboard. The behavior is the same under Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, so it must be a hardware issue. One other detail: the small "door" on SPDIF port on the motherboard had fallen out, but I doubt it has any effect on the issue.

How can I troubleshoot this? I'm suspecting I need another cable. What would be the cable specifications for at least 3 meters length?

Comment: 's/pdif with a small door' is optical toslink [I'm assuming you mean the one with the red glow]. Cables are dirt cheap these days, get a new one & test.

Comment: The thing is I'm already testing a second cable (not counting the original one). What cable brand would you recommend for quality?

Comment: toslink cables don't really have a 'quality', they either work or they don't. Glass will transmit further than plastic but is more fragile & can break internally if bent too hard. Plastic is OK up to 10m, so if you've tried several cables, I suspect you may have a clock issue. External DACs would be expected to use the computer as their clock source, so there's probably nothing adjustable at that end. Try changing your output rate from 44.1 to 48, test, change it back, test. See which works best.

Comment: My DAC should support 44.1, 48 and 96 kHz. With the first cable I tried 44.1 and 48 flat out didn't work, and 96 kHz had much more of this going-silent thing. With the second cable, 44.1 and 48 work, as well as 96, yet there are still those things with audio output silent for a second. I was expecting the behavior to be more predictable, especially since the interface is digital, and it's supposed to just send PCM samples end-to-end...

Comment: There's very little you can do to analyse either transmission or reception, short of making sure the light hasn't gone out during these gaps. All I can suggest is try another transmitter & another receiver [& I'm aware that's not the simplest of tasks, practically].